# нормированный остаток линейной регрессии в r

Tags: r

Как в `r` вывести нормированный остаток линейной регрессии, который должен быть не больше 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пакет `MASS` содержит нужную функцию:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
MASS::stdres(fit)
#>           Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag          Datsun 710 
#>        -0.722665892        -0.497989835        -1.492373347 
#>      Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet Sportabout             Valiant 
#>         0.069814926         0.424508711        -1.016854668 
#>          Duster 360           Merc 240D            Merc 230 
#>        -0.039642050         0.877856641        -1.203440451 
#>            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE 
#>         0.250230124        -0.664146151         1.007109273 
#>          Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood 
#>         0.713846540        -0.232206716        -0.779573249 
#> Lincoln Continental   Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128 
#>        -0.243509505         1.906196146         1.926839929 
#>         Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla       Toyota Corona 
#>         0.271816032         1.890244243        -1.074315562 
#>    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28 
#>        -0.615748835        -1.051583271        -0.002953431 
#>    Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2 
#>         1.061707341        -0.404738025        -0.094024693 
#>        Lotus Europa      Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino 
#>         1.382605855        -1.996242099         0.002984249 
#>       Maserati Bora          Volvo 142E 
#>         0.668478702        -1.329692005
```